# JPA: Should cascading from SQL script be reflected in entity?

Tags: jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I have two entities: `course` and `category` that are associated by the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int categoryId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
            name="course_category",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    )
    private Set<Course> courses;
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int courseId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Add the course's title!")
    private String title;
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private Set<Category> categories;
}
```

My goal is that after deleting a category, the courses related to that category will not be deleted, only the association must be broken So I included `ON DELETE CASCADE` when creating the join table.

```
  CREATE TABLE course_category (
    category_id INT NOT NULL,
    course_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id)
        REFERENCES categories(category_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id)
        REFERENCES courses(course_id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, course_id)
)
```

If I am not wrong it should do my goal.
But now my question is: Should I reflect `ON DELETE CASCADE` in my entity? If so, how can I do it? By adding CascadeType.REMOVE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid `on delete cascade` with JPA because that way the database will delete rows that may be still present in the JPA persistence context.

Instead use `CascadeType.REMOVE` and/or `orphanRemoval=true` to cascade JPA remove operations.

Comment: "database will delete rows that may be still present in the JPA persistence context." can you explain it in more detail?

Comment: If you load data with JPA you have entities in memory. Now you are deleting one of the entities and the cascade will also remove the relations. But in the memory you still have the entities.